# Calculating the time of function calls vs system calls in C

Tags: c, linux

I'm trying to compare function call using the clock_gettime but I'm getting weird results.

```
#include <sys/time.h> 
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


int myppid(){
  int myarray[] = {1,2};
  return(myarray[1]);
}

main(int argc, char **argv){

  uint64_t diff,diff1,diff2;
  struct timespec start,end;
  int billion = 1000000000;
  int i;

  /*** for loop to find average overhead ***/

  clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &start);   //start clock
  for (i; i<1000000; i++);                  //waste time
  clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &end);     //end clock

  diff = billion * ( end.tv_sec - start.tv_sec) + end.tv_nsec - start.tv_nsec;

  printf("elapsed time of empty for loop: %llu nanoseconds\n", (long long unsigned int) diff);


  /***  myppid to find average overhead of a local function  ****/

  clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &start);   //start clock
  for (i; i<1000000; i++)                   //waste time
    {myppid();}
  clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &end);     //end clock

  diff1 = billion * ( end.tv_sec - start.tv_sec) + end.tv_nsec - start.tv_nsec;
  //diff1 = diff1 - diff;
  printf("elapsed time of for loop of myppid: %llu nanoseconds\n", (long long unsigned int) diff1);


  // getppid.c to find average overhead of the system call


 clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &start);   //start clock
  for (i; i<1000000; i++)                   //waste time
    {getppid();}
  clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &end);     //end clock

  diff2 = billion * ( end.tv_sec - start.tv_sec) + end.tv_nsec - start.tv_nsec;
  //diff2 = diff2 - diff1;
  printf("elapsed time of for loop of getppid: %llu nanoseconds\n", (long long unsigned int) diff2);

  exit(0);
}
```

I'm excepting to get increasing clock numbers in nanoseconds but I get:

elapsed time of empty for loop: 421 nanoseconds
   
elapsed time of for loop of myppid: 160 nanoseconds
   
elapsed time of for loop of getppid: 195 nanoseconds

Comment: Due to compiler optimizations making function calls can fill the CPU pipeline and actually be faster than an empty loop.

Comment: An you should probably try to increase the number of iterations to where it takes a few seconds to compare. Times in the sub-millisecond range are not going to be very accurate..

Comment: Anyway to change that?

Comment: Even a brain-dead optimizer will likely eliminate your first "waste time" loop.

Comment: Any advice on how I can find the average overhead for a loop function?

Comment: I'd just use a profiler. When I experimented with this code, the first pass always took 4410000 ns regardless of which one it was, probably because of something related to library loading.

Comment: Aside from that, imho you'd make things more readable if you printed (as a double) nanoseconds/iteration

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#include <sys/time.h> 
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


int myppid(){
  int myarray[] = {1,2};
  return(myarray[1]);
}

main(int argc, char **argv){

uint64_t diff,diff1,diff2;
struct timespec start,end;
int billion = 1000000000;
int i;
// getppid.c to find average overhead of the system call


clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &start);   //start clock
 for (i; i<1000000; i++)                   //waste time
   {getppid();}
 clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &end);     //end clock

 diff2 = billion * ( end.tv_sec - start.tv_sec) + end.tv_nsec - start.tv_nsec;
 //diff2 = diff2 - diff1;
 printf("elapsed time of for loop of getppid: %llu nanoseconds\n", (long long unsigned     int) diff2);

/***  myppid to find average overhead of a local function  ****/

 clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &start);   //start clock
 for (i; i<1000000; i++)                   //waste time
 {myppid();}
 clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &end);     //end clock

 diff1 = billion * ( end.tv_sec - start.tv_sec) + end.tv_nsec - start.tv_nsec;
 //diff1 = diff1 - diff;
 printf("elapsed time of for loop of myppid: %llu nanoseconds\n", (long long unsigned int) diff1);

 /*** for loop to find average overhead ***/

 clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &start);   //start clock
 for (i; i<1000000; i++);                  //waste time
 clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &end);     //end clock

 diff = billion * ( end.tv_sec - start.tv_sec) + end.tv_nsec - start.tv_nsec;

 printf("elapsed time of empty for loop: %llu nanoseconds\n", (long long unsigned int) diff);

exit(0); 
}
```

Surprisingly this code will also give you a decreasing order of time values.
But its not so surprising if you visit [this link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loop_fusion). Its a compiler optimization technique.